# jq rounding large integers when it shouldn't

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to use jq where my data has a large integer in it.  Example:

```
$ cat door.json
[
  {
    "name": "Sliding Door 2",
    "type": "MyAirtightSlideDoor",
    "id": 130597706006447927,
    "properties": {
      "OnOff": "True",
      "ShowInTerminal": "True",
      "ShowInToolbarConfig": "True",
      "ShowOnHUD": "False",
      "Open": "True"
    }
  }
]
```

Okay, that is a valid json file, I think.  But then when I ask jq to parse it, it destroys the ID integer:

```
$ cat door.json | jq '.'
[
  {
    "name": "Sliding Door 2",
    "type": "MyAirtightSlideDoor",
    "id": 130597706006447920,
    "properties": {
      "OnOff": "True",
      "ShowInTerminal": "True",
      "ShowInToolbarConfig": "True",
      "ShowOnHUD": "False",
      "Open": "True"
    }
  }
]
```

My end goal is to be able to get id out and use it to query deeper into an API, but 130597706006447920 != 130597706006447927.

I tested this with the 64 bit binary for versions 1.5, 1.4, and 1.3 on a centos 7 x86_64 AWS instance.

Any input would be awesome.

Comment: The reason this happens is because jq uses 64-bit floating point numbers internally.

Comment: Why would jq just silently destroy long integers?  Shouldn't it at least warn the user?  Any thoughts on how to stop that from happening without storing id in a string?

Comment: Sorry, but storing the ID in a string is the way to go. Not because jq is or isn't supporting it, but because IDs are supposed to be opaque identifiers whose only defining characteristic is uniqueness, while numerics carry more meanings (addition, substraction, ...)

Comment: For reference, here is an open ticket related to this issue: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/218

Answer (score 0):

you can use python json ,
It works,I have tested it.

Comment: The OP is asking for jq solution.